# Unable to connect to the server GKE/GCP x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't connect to GKE Cluster. I have everything necessary for kubectl authentication.

```
$ gke-gcloud-auth-plugin version
{
    "kind": "ExecCredential",
    "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "spec": {
        "interactive": false
    },
    "status": {
        "expirationTimestamp": "2023-11-21T18:46:36Z",
```

`$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials $NAME`

```
$ kubectl get nodes   
                                                                                                    
E1121 21:07:03.903867  109630 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://35.230.71.198/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-21T21:07:03+03:00 is before 2023-11-22T06:42:11Z
E1121 21:07:04.348742  109630 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://35.230.71.198/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-21T21:07:04+03:00 is before 2023-11-22T06:42:11Z
E1121 21:07:04.765932  109630 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://35.230.71.198/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-21T21:07:04+03:00 is before 2023-11-22T06:42:11Z
E1121 21:07:05.214094  109630 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://35.230.71.198/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-21T21:07:05+03:00 is before 2023-11-22T06:42:11Z
E1121 21:07:05.648717  109630 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://35.230.71.198/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-21T21:07:05+03:00 is before 2023-11-22T06:42:11Z
Unable to connect to the server: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-21T21:07:05+03:00 is before 2023-11-22T06:42:11Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that WSL did not have the same system time as Windows, not sure why, but running `hwclock -s` fixed this